# How is the "heart" on this webpage done in html/css/or what so ever?

Tags: html, css

I saw a page today which has a little detail, which I find, is very neat.

http://www.songkick.com/feedback

If you have a look at the right upper corner you see:

[image: We love feedback.]

I tryed to inspect the element, to how this is done and I only get this code:

```
<a href="/feedback">We <strong><span>love</span></strong> feedback</a>
```

Where is the magic? I don't see a reference to a picture for the heart or something. Where does the heart come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Then right click on the heart image and click on "Inspect Element" in the context menu.

If you are in the HTML or CSS views in Firebug then in the small pane to the right it will show the CSS rules, which are as follows (copied from Firebug):

```
#header #header-nav ul #feedback strong {
    background-image: url("http://www2.sk-static.com/images/layout/heart-small.png?20110728085037");
    background-position: 0 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

So, `background-image` is the "heart".

Happy coding.

---

And to answer "where did 'love' go?", click on the `<span>love</love>` in the HTML view (it is not selected by the above approach, presumably because it is hidden):

```
#header #header-nav ul #feedback strong span {
    display: none;
}
```

The Computed tab is also helpful to see the actual applied rules.

Answer (score 2):

The `<strong>` tag has this CSS: `background-image: url(http://www2.sk-static.com/images/layout/heart-small.png?20110728085037);`, applied from this CSS rule: `#header-nav ul #feedback strong` :)

Answer (score 2):

Using firebug, it's an image in their css.

http://www2.sk-static.com/images/layout/heart-small.png?20110728085037

[image]